# What scale should I use to measure the test results for my research?

Tags: research-undergraduate, statistics

I posted this question in the Stack Exchange for Statistics last night and so far, no one has answered yet. Please read and tell me if there's any other tag I can use for my question.

I would like to know what statistical tool I can use for my research. I am a student of Bachelor of Arts in English. I am proposing research topics, which require me to give my respondents grammar and vocabulary tests. Both tests have 25 items and the passing score is 50%. My professor requires me to have a scale for the test results. She said that it is "Any statistical tool that you can use and fits your study."

The topics I'm proposing, which require tests, are the following:

1. A Comparative Analysis of Grammar Competence between "a school I will not name" 12th Grade Students Who Watch Lucifer and Who Don’t Watch English Series to Discern Whether TV Viewing Should Be a Regular Learning Approach

2. A Comparative Analysis between "a school I will not name" 12th Grade Students Who Listen to Songs with Vocabulary Words and Who Only Memorize Meanings to Discern Whether Song Listening Should Be a Regular Learning Approach

3. A Comparative Analysis between "a school I will not name" 12th Grade Students Who Watch Video Clips with Vocabulary Words and Who Only Read Sample Sentences to Discern Whether Video Watching Should Be a Regular Learning Approach

I need to have at least 30 respondents who will answer my multiple-choice grammar and vocabulary test. I need to prove that there is a problem in either grammar or vocabulary in the 12th grade of the school. What scale should I use to measure the results? My professor gave the Likert scale as an example. I just know that this is used to measure the intensity of an answer. Can this be also used to measure test results?

I already have 30 respondents and 12 of them failed the vocabulary test. What statistical tool can be used to show that the problem in vocabulary is significant? The mean, median, and mode scores for the test are a passing score so I can't use any of the three as the tool. I tried using z-score but it only made the number of those who got 50% of the score lower.